# How to bundle client-side components (js/less/css/img)

Tags: node.js, web, gruntjs, bower, gulp

As a team, we've established a client-side components library. Each component has some assets (JS/LESS/CSS/IMG/FONTS). Currently I've explored that for describing clien-side components, I can use Bower / Component (if there are any other please let me know). **But I don't know how (or even if it is possible) to bundle components**. Let's consider a scenario:

1. So now, I have each component described (with Bower/Component or whatever), example:

   - Component A has a dependency to jQuery, jQuery UI
   - Component B has a dependency to underscore, jQuery, Component A
   - Component C has a dependency to Component B
   - Component D has a dependency to Component A
2. I would like to bundle them in a web application. For instance I would like to specify that my application uses Component C & D. And as a result I would have a:

   - JavaScript bundle (bundle.js) with all necessary scripts from Component C + JavaScript from the dependencies
   - CSS bundle (bundle.css) with all necessary styles from Component C + CSS from dependencies. As I use LESS, it would be nice to have a LESS -> CSS transform in the middle.
3. And now the ultimate task: in my web app I would like to include only single JavaScript bundle.js and single css bundle.css.

I could imagine, there's a tool that checks components' metadata (bower.json/component.json/package.json) and does the analysis of CSS/JS dependencies graph and includes needed files only once in output bundles. But how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

You're asking two different things:

1. How to manage dependencies
2. How to bundle all resources into one file

So you'll need two tools to get to your desired result (nr. 3 in your list).

### Managing dependencies with Bower

On our current project we're using Bower to manage each sub-project's dependencies. Bower will install all necessary dependencies for you. So if these are the bower files of your projects:

```
Component A | Component B | Component C | Component D
-jQuery     | -underscore | -Component B| -Component A
-jQuery UI  | -jQuery     |             |
            | -Component A|             |
```

And you would list Component C and B as a dependency (again in Bower) of your web application, this is the list of dependencies Bower will install for you:

- jQuery
- jQuery UI
- underscore
- Component A
- Component B

*On a sidenote, if there's a difference in jQuery versions of A and B you'll need to choose one.*

### Bundling all resources into one file

Once you have the correct list of dependencies in your web application you'll need to set up a process to bundle these into two files (`bundle.js` & `bundle.css`). You can do this any way you like, but I would suggest using a JavaScript task runner such as Grunt or Gulp. You can find plenty of information on Google on how to set up concatenation tasks.

We use Grunt and make use of the `grunt-usemin` task. I've [blogged a minimalistic guide](http://tanciaux.wordpress.com/2014/02/05/mumug-the-minimal-usemin-use-guide/) how to set this up. Alternatively you could simply use the [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) task for this (grunt-usemin uses this as well).

Comment: Thanks! One thing though: for instance if in my webapp I use only Component D, will Grunt/Gulp tasks automatically include dependencies? Or I need to manually concat Component A, jQuery & jQuery UI?

Comment: In Grunt/Gulp you need to manually configure which files you want concatenated. Interesting question though, need to see if there's a task available that would automatically concatenate all your Bower components.